# facebook wall post Javascript code gives error loading source error in flex 4.5

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, facebook-javascript-sdk, flex4.5

I am using flex 4.5. I have created javascript function named postToWall() to post on wall of facebook.  But when I call javascript function it does not execute any code.  I traced this code in firefox 35.0.1 then I found that while calling javascript function it says  “error loading source” error.

I am using following code to post wall on facebook.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> 
   <head>
     <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function postToWall() {

                var word   = document.getElementById("myWord").innerHTML;
                var params = {};
                params['message'] = word;
                params['name'] = 'test';
                params['description'] = 'test';
                params['link'] = 'asas.com';
                params['picture'] = 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/--jbgq-gytJQ/URaJHK_93LI/AAAAAAAAAF0/SkyoK7H3r7U/s1600/Simple+Apple.png';
                params['caption'] = 'test';

               FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
                 if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert('Error occured');
                  } else {
                  alert(word);
                }
                });

          }
           window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
              FB.init({
                   appId  : 'appId', 
                   status : true,
                  cookie : true,
                   xfbml  : true, 
                  oauth  : true
              });
          };
           // Load the SDK Asynchronously
         (function(d){
          var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
         }(document));
     </script>
  </head>
 <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <fb:login-button perms="publish_stream">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
    <a href="javascript:postToWall()">Post To Wall</a>
</body>
```